# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ws.core.soap.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement

Tags: web-services, jboss, jax-ws, soapui, ibm-sterling

I am working on **IBM Sterling V 9.3**. I have exposed an Service as **JAX-WS web service** using the steps provided in the knowledge center successfully on **Jboss 4.2.3** app server. EAR file got deployed successfully and app server started fine. I could see the generated WSDL file for the web service.

When I tried to access the WSDL from **soapUI tool (version 3.5.1)**, I am getting the following error in the response message. I searched for the same and found out that we should have following jars under JBOSS_HOME\lib\endorsed folder:

•   jboss-saaj.jar

•   jboss-jaxws.jar

•   jboss-jaxrpc.jar

•   jaxb-api-2.1.9.jar

•   xercesImpl.jar

•   xalan.jar

•   serializer.jar

I have added above jars but still getting the same error. Can share the more details if required. Please help.

**Error message:**

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ws.core.soap.TextImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPElement</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**WSDL file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions name="SearsBeansService"
    targetNamespace="http://webservices.sears.com/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://webservices.sears.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import
                namespace="http://webservices.sears.com/documentation/SearsGetOrderListForWSCService/searsGetOrderListForWSCService/output" schemaLocation="SearsBeansService_schema1.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import
                namespace="http://webservices.sears.com/documentation/SearsGetOrderListForWSCService/searsGetOrderListForWSCService/input" schemaLocation="SearsBeansService_schema2.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import
                namespace="http://webservices.sears.com/documentation/SearsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService/searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService/output" schemaLocation="SearsBeansService_schema3.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import
                namespace="http://webservices.sears.com/documentation/SearsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService/searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService/input" schemaLocation="SearsBeansService_schema4.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://webservices.sears.com/" schemaLocation="SearsBeansService_schema5.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import
                namespace="http://www.sterlingcommerce.com/documentation/types" schemaLocation="yfctype.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService">
        <part element="tns:searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService" name="parameters"/>
    </message>
    <message name="searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCServiceResponse">
        <part element="tns:searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCServiceResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </message>
    <message name="XBeanWSException">
        <part element="tns:XBeanWSException" name="fault"/>
    </message>
    <message name="searsGetOrderListForWSCService">
        <part element="tns:searsGetOrderListForWSCService" name="parameters"/>
    </message>
    <message name="searsGetOrderListForWSCServiceResponse">
        <part element="tns:searsGetOrderListForWSCServiceResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SearsBeans">
        <operation name="searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService">
            <input message="tns:searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService"/>
            <output message="tns:searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCServiceResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:XBeanWSException" name="XBeanWSException"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="searsGetOrderListForWSCService">
            <input message="tns:searsGetOrderListForWSCService"/>
            <output message="tns:searsGetOrderListForWSCServiceResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:XBeanWSException" name="XBeanWSException"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SearsBeansPortBinding" type="tns:SearsBeans">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="searsGetOrderDetailsForWSCService">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="XBeanWSException">
                <soap:fault name="XBeanWSException" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
        <operation name="searsGetOrderListForWSCService">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="XBeanWSException">
                <soap:fault name="XBeanWSException" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SearsBeansService">
        <port binding="tns:SearsBeansPortBinding" name="SearsBeansPort">
            <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve this issue. I had to remove all the white spaces, comments and question marks (?) from the request (if any).

After that it was working fine. I think, due to the white spaces in request, soapUI was treating it as some kind of request element/value and was unable to convert into SOAPElement.

Hope this would be helpful for others !

Answer (score 1):

Under Request Properties, set "Strip whitespaces" to true. This must be done for each new request. I didn't find a way to set true by default. 
Questions marks are placeholders for parameters that must be supplied in your request.